# OpenStack newton dashboard unreachable CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos, redhat, openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack newton on centos 7 server. Everything is working fine But I am unable to connect dashboard.

Here is my all observation.

```
[root@controller hpchost1]# service httpd status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─openstack-dashboard.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-01-04 05:46:13 UTC; 20s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 4113 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4157 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py compress --force (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4133 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4180 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─4180 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4182 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4183 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4184 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4185 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4186 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4187 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4188 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4189 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4190 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4191 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4192 (wsgi:keystone- -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4193 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4194 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4195 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4196 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─4197 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/actions-delete-selected.template.html'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/action-list.scss'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/split-button.html'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/actions.controller.js'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/actions.directive.js'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/actions.detail.mock.html'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/actions.custom.mock.html'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/action-list.module.js'
Jan 04 05:45:59 controller python[4133]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/action-list/button-tooltip.directive.js'
Jan 04 05:46:13 controller systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

My httpd error.log

```
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.403879 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4601] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.405399 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 4601] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.423890 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4601] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.424849 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4601] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.440126 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4601] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 04 05:52:03.440161 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4601] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

my openstack-dashboard.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard
WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi
Alias /dashboard/static /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am unable to figure out the problem. everything looks fine for me. Please help me to figure out the problem.

Thank in advance. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of ports that you need to take care of , in an openstack deployment. For dashboard , you can just open port 80.

[List of ports , openstack](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/firewalls-default-ports.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Sadly, this is a bug introduced by a package upgrade from Centos (I think from Centos 7.4 series). In order to solve it you need to change your "`/etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack-dashboard.conf`" file to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard
WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi
Alias /dashboard/static /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart httpd: `systemctl restart httpd`.

> NOTE: The missing item is: WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}